Inkscape: update size of linked image when source changes
I have linked some images generated by matplotlib into an inkscape layout. They are not in their final form. It's nice that I can change my code, save the image out to the existing name, and see the image update in inkscape. However, if I change the image's dimensions, it still stays the same size in inkscape. Is there any way to automatically change the size of an image to that of its source file?

What you are describing is the normal and expected behaviour of Inkscape. I don't think this can be changed (as far as I know). When you import a linked image, its size is set in the XML. Overwriting the linked image fill will update the image when you go back into inkscape, but won't change the width or height because it's already set. It might be possible with some scripting though.
